Converting T-SQL OUTER APPLY to EF
I been trying to convert this T-SQL code to EF, but I am not having much luck. Any help would be great.
Update with the table, Using the meetingId 1 I would to return a list of ContinuedMeetingIds. So in this example I want to return 2,3.
table
MeetingId       ContinuedMeetingId
----------      -------------
1               2
2               3
3               null


SELECT
    Prev2.ContinuedMeetingId AS PreviousValue
FROM
    [Meeting] This
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT
         prev.ContinuedMeetingId
     FROM
         [Meeting] prev
     WHERE
         Prev.ContinuedMeetingId < This.MeetingId) Prev2
WHERE
    This.MeetingId = 2710

EF / Linq:
var query1 = (from m in db.Meetings
              where m.MeetingId == MeetingId
              select new
                     {
                         m,
                         SubName = db.Meetings
                                     .Where(s => m.MeetingId == s.MeetingId)
                                     .Select(s => s.ContinuedMeetingId)
                     }).ToList();


Expand your example a little more. As it stands you could just SELECT ContinuedMeetingId FROM Meetings WHERE ContinuedMeetingId > @meetingIdParameter. But do all the meetings really chain linearly like this, or can you have multiple "starting" meetings (e.g. add 4, NULL to the list) or branches (add 1, 5 and 5, null)? It looks like you're asking to recursively traverse the relationship tree to find all the descendants of a node. If that's the case you'll want to define a view that uses a CTE for the recursion.

Technically I think this gives you something more like what your original query does:
var query1 = (from m in db.Meetings
              where m.MeetingId == MeetingId
              select new
                     {
                         m,
                         ContinuedMeetingsIds = db.Meetings
                            .Where(s => s.ContinuedMeetingId < m.MeetingId)
                            .Select(s => s.ContinuedMeetingId)
                     }).ToList();

But it seems pretty weird to get values that are less than the given meeting ID. I haven't encountered any data models where this query would make sense. Are you sure this is what you're going for?

so basically I need the continued meeting id of the continued meeting id using the meetingId. If the parent is the meetingId I need all the child ids using the continuedId

Have you tried your query? It is different from expected. Select do not change  cardinality of the returned data. OP, ChatGPT should answer this trivial questions with ease.

@Jefferson: If the ContinuedMeetingId is matching the MeetingId, and you select ContinuedMeetingId, then all you're going to end up with is the same value you provided for the MeetingId. I can't see how that's valuable. Please update your question with sample data and the results you'd like to see from your query based on that sample data.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv: I'm not convinced anyone really knows what's "expected" in this case. ChatGPT can provide code, but it's unlikely to be helpful. OP needs to clarify what they're actually hoping to get out of this query.

@StriplingWarrior I updated the question with the table and the data I am looking at returning.
